# wordpress admin ajax don't work

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

i'm making a plugin for sending messages to users
and i'm using ajax in the plugin 
and i'm not getting it the right way 
here is my jQuery code
i tryed many times but i cant get it done

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).ajaxStop(function () {
        $.unblockUI();
    });

    //if form is submitted
    $('#whatsappform').submit(function (e) {
        if ($('#whatsappform').validate().form() === false) {
            return false;
        }

        //Store original html to replace back in box later.
        var original = $('#faketextbox').html();
        //Scan html code for emojis and replace with text and special marker.
        $('#faketextbox img').each(function (index) {
            var emojiUnicode = this.outerHTML.match(/emoji-(.*?)"/)[1];
            $(this).replaceWith('##' + emojiUnicode + '##');
        });
        //Replace all BR's with line breaks.
        var message = $.trim($('#faketextbox').html().replace(/<br\s?\/?>/g, "\n"));
        //Copy the corrected message text to our hidden input field to be serialised.
        $('#message').val($('#faketextbox').html(message).text());
        //Replace the corrected text with the original html so it shows properly on a browser.
        $('#faketextbox').html(original);
        //Continue with the form.
        var formData = $("#whatsappform").serialize();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://localhost:81/wp/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
            cache: false,
            data: formData,
            dataType: "json",
            timeout: 45000,
            success: onSuccess,
            error: onError,
            //beforeSend: function(jqXHR, settings) {
            //},
            complete: function () {
                $.unblockUI();
            }
        });

        return false;
    });

</script>
```

sorry for the bad english :)

Comment: Please post the least amount of code that highlights your problem.

Comment: OK, thanks for doing that. Now please provide exactly what isn't working, any error messages you receive (either client or server side), etc. The more you provide then the more likely we'll be able to help you.

Comment: id write some functions for messages on success but it always geting error when it success :( could you provide my with a gudie to do it right on the same page :)

Answer (score 0):

WordPress expects your JS in [noconflict](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) mode, wrap the code as follows:

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
    // Code that uses jQuery's $ can follow here.
});
```

Comment: thats did ok but i get this

Success: The ajax call was successful but there was an error with the data returned: HTTP Status:200StatusTextOK

what should i do 
@diggy